# Cannot consume json with java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having trouble making an entity object that will consume this json...

```
{"AS400":{"lcpDBConfigs":{"PR":{"userNameAutoProvisionFlag":false,"userNameOverrideFlag":true,"urlSelection":{"isRestrictedToChoices":false,"choices":["jdbc:as400://<hostname>;databaseName=<dbName>"],"validationPattern":".*"}}}}}
```

I have tried the following but I know I am leaving off the AS400..

Will someone please help? I am new to consuming json with java ovjects...

```
public static class LcpDBConfig {
        private Boolean userNameAutoProvisionFlag;
        private Boolean userNameOverrideFlag;
        private Selection urlSelection;

        public LcpDBConfig(Boolean userNameAutoProvisionFlag, Boolean userNameOverrideFlag, Selection urlSelection){
            this.userNameAutoProvisionFlag = userNameAutoProvisionFlag;
            this.userNameOverrideFlag = userNameOverrideFlag;
            this.urlSelection = urlSelection;
        }

        public Boolean getUserNameAutoProvisionFlag() {
            return userNameAutoProvisionFlag;
        }

        public void setUserNameAutoProvisionFlag(Boolean userNameAutoProvisionFlag) {
            this.userNameAutoProvisionFlag = userNameAutoProvisionFlag;
        }

        public Boolean getUserNameOverrideFlag() {
            return userNameOverrideFlag;
        }

        public void setUserNameOverrideFlag(Boolean userNameOverrideFlag) {
            this.userNameOverrideFlag = userNameOverrideFlag;
        }

        public Selection getUrlSelection() {
            return urlSelection;
        }

        public void setUrlSelection(Selection urlSelection) {
            this.urlSelection = urlSelection;
        }

        public static class Selection {
            private Boolean isRestrictedToChoices;
            private List<String> choices;
            private String validationPattern;

            public Selection(Boolean isRestrictedToChoices, List<String> choices, String validationPattern){
                this.isRestrictedToChoices = isRestrictedToChoices;
                this.choices = choices;
                this.validationPattern = validationPattern;
            }

            public Boolean getIsRestrictedToChoices() {
                return isRestrictedToChoices;
            }

            public void setIsRestrictedToChoices(Boolean isRestrictedToChoices) {
                this.isRestrictedToChoices = isRestrictedToChoices;
            }

            public List<String> getChoices() {
                return choices;
            }

            public void setChoices(List<String> choices) {
                this.choices = choices;
            }

            public String getValidationPattern() {
                return validationPattern;
            }

            public void setValidationPattern(String validationPattern) {
                this.validationPattern = validationPattern;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My issue is that it is a map inside a map... This is not a duplicate of the other.

Comment: but what is your question?

Comment: What is wrong with my entity object? It is not consuming the json b/c it is not formatted correctly...

Comment: Well, your object doesn't have a field called AS400, so Gson won't know what to do with the AS400 field in the JSON...

Comment: It's not always named AS400... It will change... It will be the key to the map.